# Java Swing - More efficient to draw in multiple panels or a single panel

Tags: java, swing

If one has the choice between doing all rendering in a single JPanel or rendering across multiple JPanels (with override paintComponent) and one is not using any other Swing component such as JButtons, JTextBoxes, JComboBoxes, etc (other than the JFrame that the panel or panels reside in).  If one is only drawing using drawLine, drawRectangle, fillRect, etc.  Is it more efficient to draw everything in one panel or spread the drawing out over multiple panels? Assume that the code complexity is the same either way and reducing lag / improving response time is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slightly more efficient.

However, consider using several panels and rely on the layout managers to handle sizing etc. It will most likely simplify your code. If you are using one panel only you will have to handle resizing yourself.

In programming, don't optimise before you know performance is a problem.  Measure!

Comment: "In programming, don't optimise before you know performance is a problem. Measure!"  Agree, but to do that would require implementing two different ways.  If it's straight-forward to implement either way, might as well do that from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Swing will only paint a component when it needs to.

If the entire frame is repainted every time a property changes, then keep the logic together in a single place for ease of maintenance.

If it is logical to break the panel down into sub components, then you can repaint individual sub components as necessary.

For example, this is the way a JTable works. You can have a hundred row in the table, but if you only change the data in one row, then only that row is repainted.